# Xamarin Forms Bug?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In one of the standard Pixel device emulators, while running your app, if you go into "sleep" mode by pressing the power button, then wake the device up-- and do this **twice** -- then the UI becomes unresponsive, but actions will fire if you press buttons--you just won't see the UI update or the screen change.

EASY TO REPRODUCE:
Just create a new Xam Forms project using master detail template. Run it using one of the Pixel emulators. Browse, and then pick an item. Then do the power on/off TWO TIMES. Then click the back button. (after this, if you use the home button and then return to your running app, the correct page will now be displayed.)

Can anyone confirm this? Is it just me or my emulators? I haven't tried on a real Pixel -- I need to talk to someone who has one.

Note, this does not occur using the low-end simulator.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: Have you tried it on a new emulator instance? If its reproducible then you should file a bug in the link shared by Jason